# Надо отредактировать список в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть список, в который записываются данные построчно. Выглядит стока примерно так:
`***, ****, **,`.

Строка записывается за строкой, в строчку. Как можно добавить `\n` после строки?
Я попытался написать:

```
for i in izm:
    k=k+i
    k.extend('\n')
```

Но понял, что он просто будет вставлять текст. Помогите, пожалуйста!

```
r = requests.get('').text
lol = re.findall('на [ |\d|]+',r)
print (lol)
r = lol[0] + r.split(lol[0])[1]
izm = []
final = re.findall('td.+?>(.+?)<\/td',r)
while True:
    for i in enumerate(final):
        for _ in re.findall("td", i[1]):
            final.pop(i[0])
            continue
    break
    [final.pop(0) for i in range(5)]
final = ";".join(final).replace("\xa0","")
for i in re.split('[^;]+-\d+', final):
    gr = re.findall(f"[^;]+-\d+{i}",final)[0].split(";")
    if len(gr)>2:
        izm.append(re.findall(f"[^;]+-\d+{i}",final)[0].split(";"))
```

Comment: `lst[:k+1]+['новый текст']+lst[k+1:]`

Comment: @splash58 Немножко не понял как это работает

Comment: забираем из списка по строку номер k, добавляем новую, потом остаток списка

Comment: @DociChmoki Уточните вопрос и, пожалуйста, приведите пример кода

Comment: @dhvcc Ну, программа парсит сайт, через регулярки забирает нужную мне информацию в лист, но записывает её в строку, мне надо, чтобы между строками был пропуск строки

Comment: r = requests.get('').text
lol = re.findall('на [ |\d|]+',r)
print (lol)
r = lol[0] + r.split(lol[0])[1]
izm = []
final = re.findall('td.+?>(.+?)<\/td',r)
while True:
    for i in enumerate(final):
        for _ in re.findall("td", i[1]):
            final.pop(i[0])
            continue
    break
[final.pop(0) for i in range(5)]
final = ";".join(final).replace("\xa0","")
for i in re.split('[^;]+-\d+', final):
    gr = re.findall(f"[^;]+-\d+{i}",final)[0].split(";")
    if len(gr)>2:
        izm.append(re.findall(f"[^;]+-\d+{i}",final)[0].split(";"))

Comment: @dhvcc Не знаю понятен ли вам так код

Comment: @DociChmoki Поправьте вопрос, добавив туда код и оформите его как код (выделить и ctrl+k)

Comment: @dhvcc вот так вот

Comment: @DociChmoki for _ in re.findall("td", i[1]):  final.pop(i[0]) continue - зачем тут continue? Он ничего не делает

Comment: @dhvcc и правда

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите просто при выводе добавлять новый строку, то

```
for i in izm:
    print(i,'\n')
```

Если именно хотите всунуть отдельный элемент между другими, то используйте

```
izm.insert(индекс,'\n')
```

Это поставить \n на индекс и сместит все элементы после вправо
Еще для замены эскейп-кодов лучше использовать html.unescape(), а не str.replace

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101158/discussion-on-answer-by-dhvcc-----).